# Rails3 Console Command not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was able to run rails console in a rails directory fine, however I ran into a problem running rails console --sandbox where I was getting an error like this:

no such file to load -- readline (LoadError)

After running this command: sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libreadline5-dev
(found here http://pranshuarya.com/jaal/Development/rails-3-error-require-no-such-file-to-load-readline-loaderror.html)

I now receive the following error when running either rails console or rails console --sandbox:

Could not find mail-2.2.16 in any of the sources

I am running Ubuntu 10.10, Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3

Any ideas?

Comment: It may be helpful for you to post your Gemfile, and if you haven't already, run `bundle install` to make sure your gems are up-to-date and all installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you could be having some gem in your gemfile but you did not run bundle install to install it. Please check that out.